# How do I remove multiple object elements from a list from another in Java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have class Employee which have 3 fields.

And I have a list of DTO objects.

```
public class Employee {
   private String empId;
   private String name;
   private String group;
   private String salary;       
}


List<Employee> listEmployeesA = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
 new Employee("101"."Mark", "A", 20000),
 new Employee("102"."Tom", "B", 3000),
 new Employee("103"."Travis", "C", 5000),
 new Employee("104"."Diana", null, 3500),
 new Employee("105"."Keith", "D", 4200),
 new Employee("106"."Liam", "E", 6500),
 new Employee("107"."Whitney", "F", 6100),
 new Employee("108"."Tina", null,2900)
 new Employee("109"."Patrick", "G", 3400)
 ));


List<Employee> listEmployeesB = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
 new Employee("101"."Mark", "A", 20000),
 new Employee("103"."Travis", "C", 5000),
 new Employee("104"."Diana", null, 3500),
 ));
```

I have two list for employee class, I remove all object elements from listEmployeesA which is already in the listEmployeesB only based on only property **empId, name and group** but not the based on **salary**.

I want to do something look like below example (based on few class property):

```
listEmployeesA.removeAll(listEmployeesB);
```

Expected out below list for listEmployeesA:

```
Employee("102"."Tom", "B", 3000),
Employee("105"."Keith", "D", 4200),
Employee("106"."Liam", "E", 6500),
Employee("107"."Whitney", "F", 6100),
Employee("108"."Tina", null,2900)
Employee("109"."Patrick", "G", 3400)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `removeAll` to work with `listEmployeesA.removeAll(listEmployeesB)` by adding two methods to the `Employee` class:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals (Object other)

  @Override
  public int hashCode ()
```

When you do, in `equals`, compare only the ID, name, and group. Also, in `hashCode`, build a hash code from those fields. Exclude salary from both `equals` and `hashCode`.

If you don't know how to code a good `hashCode` or `equals` method, check your IDE for a tool that can create code for these methods.

Overriding `equals` works because `removeAll` uses `equals (Object)` to compare the elements in each `List`.  Without overriding the equals method, the `equals (Object o)` method inherited from `Object` is used, which tests to see if the references are the same.

When you override `equals` method, *always* override `hashCode` method.

Answer (score 2):

Create compound keys using the fields you are interested in from `listEmployeesB` and remove an element from `listEmployeesA` if a compound key is contained in the set:

```
Set<List<String>> set = listEmployeesB.stream()
                                .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.empId, e.name, e.group))
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

listEmployeesA.removeIf(e -> set.contains( Arrays.asList(e.empId, e.name, e.group)));
```